# Winsock multi clients and multi thread, Computer works hard

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

i'm trying to build multi clients server in c++ sockets programing, and i found some troubles at multi threads. i use _beginthread to create some threads. when we'd like to build multiclients server, i think we should have a thread that handle socket accepter anytime with looping, and so far it works fine (no trouble on me).

afterward i make some threads to handle **Client-DataReceiver** and i think it's better than we create 1 thread to handle all clients with loop the entire clients alternately. multi threads would do better since they work synchronously, i think.

when i'm done it all, the server works so slow/hard and they even use till 100% cpu usage??
and perhaps there's something missing/wrong on my code?

```
   void Initialize(){
      [....Server initialize goes here...]
       _beginthread( acceptNewClient, 0, (void*)1);  //the thread that handle accepter
    }
    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    void acceptNewClient(void* arg)
{
    while(true){
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket,NULL,NULL);
    if (ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        char value = 1;
        setsockopt( ClientSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof( value ) );
        Client_Socket *client = new Client_Socket(ClientSocket); 
        _beginthread(ReceiveFromClient, 1,client );   //handle of client data receiver
        client_list.push_back(client);
    }
  }     
}
void ReceiveFromClient(void* client_sockets)
{
   Client_Socket * client_socket = (Client_Socket*)client_sockets;
   while(true){
       server->doReceive();    
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

after figuring out this case i think the causer is thread itself
i have even tried in new console project:

```
#include <process.h>
    void tes(void * arg){
        while(true){

        }
    }
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    _beginthread( tes, 0, (void*)1);
    while(true){}
        return 0;
    }
```

the thread feels too hard for computer, and i think the mistake is the thread itself.
those code really make CPU 100% CPU, is there something wrong for my thread code or solution to solve this case?

Comment: This code is a bit confusing and incomplete... Why is `ClientReceiver()` calling a server function? Shouldn't it just receive/send using its local socket?

Comment: i'm sorry, if it incomplete, but im trying to make it clear. ClientReceiver() is still in server, they used to handle Clients service. there are 2 class in Server side first: "server class" the place where we put the clients socket list, and second: "client handle service" it used to handle the service from client computer such as sending data from client to server, and receive data from client to server.

Comment: What kind of server is it ? Brief connections, without communication between connected clients ? (eg. HTTP) Or something like a chat server with a shared global state ? (eg. IRC). Please be careful that different types of servers might call for different architectures.

Comment: i'm making system information which send some small data each other but i'm sure, how it works, it just like chat

Comment: What does doReceive() do?

Comment: doReceive() it doesn't do anything which makes heavy. it just: recv(currentSocket, buffer, bufSize, 0);

i was trying to figure out what does the mistake whether the thread itself or the code in the thread side and turn out the thread is the causer, the computer would feels heavy if accommodate more than one thread. is there something wrong with my thread?

Comment: That's not 'nothing': that's a system call. More questions. Why are you passing an unused parameter to ReceiveFromClient()? Are these sockets in non-blocking mode by any chance? What is 'bufSize'? Are you checking for end of stream? and errors? And if so, how are you causing doReceive() to exit that spin loop? Please post the relevant code. And I suggest you stop guessing. Threads don't have the effects you are ascribing to them.

Comment: well, firstly i pass argument to thread only a pointer to the instance so that the thread able to call anything from socket client handler instance such as receive/close socket/send data from particular computer that has been passed on the argument before. and the spin loop able to exit if the sockets are really closed. i'm sorry because i haven't posted the complete code..
but i'm sure the mistake is the thread.. if you try my edit code that i have posted, just see that and the cpu would be 100%. but if not, there something missing on my system. i'm using Windows 7 OS

Comment: The argument remains unused. Please post the code of the ReceiveFromClient() method as you were asked before. You've answered none of my questions. I can help you, but only if you help yourself by answering what I ask.

Comment: This is a little tip. If you are using a **infinite while loop** to handle a **little work load** inside the loop, according to my experience it's better to add **thread sleep** at the end.
In windows just add `sleep(1);` at the end of the while loop. It avoids 100% cpu usage problem.

And you are claiming that 100% cpu usage occurs because of the thread. But what I experience is if you write a simple cpp with just a `while(true);` in the main method (I mean single thread), you will definitely ended up with 100% cpu usage.

Answer (score 2):

As I hinted some hours ago, the cause of this is that you have put your socket into non-blocking mode for some reason, and you're not using select(), just spin looping around recv(). It doesn't make sense anyway, as you are using a thread per connection.

The solution isn't to put to socket back into blocking mode, as per your answer, but to *remove* the code that sets non-blocking mode in the first place, blocking mode being the default, as pointed out by @cHao.

Answer (score 1):

100% CPU is most likely caused by while loop (`while(true) server->doReceive();`). Proper way to use sockets is to wait on a socket until there is something useful to be done with it. Standard C++ function that enables this is [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

More advanced approach would be to use I/O completion ports, but at your stage that technique is too advanced, and probably not even needed.

Comment: i have even gotten rid of the start thread code. and leave only 1 thread alive at Accepter Server. the cpu reduced to around 50%.
is there something wrong with this code?
i start this thread in class
_beginthread(ReceiveFromClient, 1,client );
 _beginthread( acceptNewClient, 0, (void*)1);

Comment: @Rizky I don't know what code are you referring to, but it does not matter. Stack Overflow is not meant for questions "is there something wrong here", but for questions "I have such and such problem, where I expect one thing but experience another". Post another question that is clearly of second type and someone should help you. If you want to ask a question of the first type please go to [codereview.se].

Comment: yea,, it's ok if this question is not clear. i will try to make another question clearly. but this case is really happen to me. the computer does not able to do many thread. here it's i was wondering how does it can..

Comment: Minor nit picking, "select" is actually a Berkeley/Posix sockets API function call (which Winsock supports), it's not Standard C++.

Comment: +1 for I/O completion ports. I agree it's likely too complex for the original question. However, Rizky, if you want to learn about IOCP then I have some free code and articles here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

Answer (score -1):

i found out the problem. firstly if you'd like to build server with thread every client, the first thing that must be aware is:

> make sure you've set the SOCKET to blocking mode beforehand with [ioctlsocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

this actually exceedingly make sense!
well, when we were creating thread like this:

```
unsigned __stdcall threadFunc(void * arg) 
{   
    while(1) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

looks so simple thread code, but it was a matter that causing cpu works so hard.
when the recv winsocks's function called with non blocking mode, they will always repeat to the while statement goes when there's nothing data longer to read, they spun in as fast as comp works. of course this not good idea.
so if we want overcome it of course the proper way is: set socket to the nonblock.

```
u_long iMode = 0;
iResult = ioctlsocket(ClientSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
```

when recv() Socket called the machine will be waiting till they got some bytes to read. with this way 'fast spun in' won't happen anymore

thanks anyway..

Comment: Blocking mode is the default; you shouldn't need extra code to set it.  If you've set the socket as non-blocking without a good reason, *that* was your error.